# Comapre number range or char to get the result in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

RSC by comparing values from tab.col1 , tab.col2 ,tab.col3 ,tab.col4 to Result.INTR

Tab table has 1000s of rows

If any of the col1 to 4 has NULL then return 1

```
Col1 will hold values pertaining to RID = 10
Col2 will hold values pertaining to RID = 20
Col3 will hold values pertaining to RID = 30
Col4 will hold values pertaining to RID = 40
```

For eg:

```
    if tab.col1 is 3 then 4 
    if tab.col2 is 'R' then 3       
    if tab.col3 is 1900 then it query should give 4
    if 1945 then 3
    if 1937 then 3 (lower bound is less than and upper bound is greater than equal to)
    if tab.col4 is 6 then 5

and so on.....


Result table
     RID     INTR       RSC
     -----    -----      ----- 
      10        1         0
      10        2         1
      10        3         4                         
      10        4         2
      20        I         4
      20        R         3
      20        U         1
      30     1900         5
      30     1900-1937    4
      30     1937-1967    3
      30     1967         3
      40      3-4         2
      40      1-3         1
      40      4           5
```

Answer (score 0):

Check CASE and DECODE functions of Oracle.Google and check some examples.You will be able to implement your requirement with them.

For example check this one http://www.club-oracle.com/forums/case-and-decode-two-powerfull-constructs-of-sql-t181/

Comment: Ya but there is a range also 1900-1937 , I need to incorporate that logic too, so I was thinking if some reg_exp is there to figure it out

Comment: Then use regex functions of oracle to compare in your case or decode statement

Comment: You need to be clear in your explanations. How do you want to compare ranges?

Answer (score 0):

You would do this like:

```
select (case when tab.col1 = 3 then 4
             when tab.col2 = 'R' then 3
             when tab.col3 = 1900 then 4
             when tab.col3 in (1945, 1937) then 3
             when tab.col4 = 6 then 5
        . . .
```

Comment: I don't want to hard core the values of col1/col2/col3/col4..something like when tab.col1 = result.intr then ....

Comment: @RajA . . . Then I would say that your question is entirely unclear on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select t1.RSC, t2.RSC, t3.RSC, t4.RSC
from your_table tab join Result t1 on t1.RID=10 and t1.INTR=tab.col1
     join Result t2 on t2.RID=20 and t2.INTR=tab.col2
     join Result t3 on t3.RID=30 and t3.INTR >= regexp_substr(tab.col3, '^\d*') and t3.INTR <= regexp_substr(tab.col3, '\d*$')
     join Result t4 on t4.RID=40 and t4.INTR >= regexp_substr(tab.col4, '^\d*') and t4.INTR <= regexp_substr(tab.col4, '\d*$')
```